# Find Object inside Array inside another Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming

```
let bigArray = [
{
    Name: 'Trump',
    children: [
                 {Name: 'TrumpChild1', City: 'city1'}, 
                 {Name: 'TrumpChild2', City: 'city2'}
    ]
},
{
    Name: 'Barack Obama',
    children: [
                 {Name: 'Barack Obama Child1', City: 'city3'}, 
                 {Name: 'Barack Obama Child2', City: 'city4'}
    ]
},
{
    Name: 'Clinton',
    children: [
                 {Name: 'Clinton Child 1', City: 'city5'}, 
                 {Name: 'Clinton Child2', City: 'city6'}
    ]
},
```

]

I want find a object from array inside another array

```
bigArray.find(b => b.children.find(c=>c.City === 'city1'))
```

the code above return the ARRAY father

```
bigArray.forEach(b => b.children.find(c=>c.City === 'city1'))
```

and this return undefined

What's the best way to return the desired object ?

Comment: You want this `{Name: 'TrumpChild1', City: 'city1'}`?

Comment: Can be, and in my truth code i change it for a variable. =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can first flaten this array to an array of inner objects and then use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
let bigArray = [
  {
      Name: 'Trump',
      children: [
                   {Name: 'TrumpChild1', City: 'city1'}, 
                   {Name: 'TrumpChild2', City: 'city2'}
      ]
  },
  {
      Name: 'Barack Obama',
      children: [
                   {Name: 'Barack Obama Child1', City: 'city3'}, 
                   {Name: 'Barack Obama Child2', City: 'city4'}
      ]
  },
  {
      Name: 'Clinton',
      children: [
                   {Name: 'Clinton Child 1', City: 'city5'}, 
                   {Name: 'Clinton Child2', City: 'city6'}
      ]
  }
];

let all = bigArray.reduce((prev, next) => prev.concat(next.children), []);
let result = all.find(obj => obj.City === 'city1');
console.log(result);

// if there can be multiple matches then use filter
let results = all.filter(obj => obj.City === 'city1');
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks, I think understood, I must first generate a new array and then do the search.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it without flattening the array.

```
let matches = [];

// using array.forEach(), plus && in .map() to shorten the comparison syntax
bigArray.forEach(obj => {obj.children.map(c => c.City == 'city1' &&  matches.push(c))});

// and this version works even if there is not a `children` property
bigArray.forEach(obj => {obj.children && obj.children.map(c => c.City == 'city1' &&  matches.push(c))});
```

Answer (score 1):

Children could be born in the same city and so [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is not particularly well-suited for this problem as it only returns the first result its looking for. In this case [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is the function we need.

Below, we call `filter` *inside* of [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). This is different from the other answer as it does not iterate thru your input data more than once. The other answer will first create an entire array of children, then in a second iteration, select the ones that match your city query.

Alternatively, this answer iterates thru each president once and adds any matching children to the result along the way.

```
const findByCity = (city, data = {}) =>
  data .reduce
    ( (result, { children = [] }) =>
        result .concat (children .filter (c => c.city === city))
    , []
    )
```

In your input data, each child has a unique city, so it doesn't yield a good demonstration. I've added some more children born in `city5` so we can see an answer that includes multiple children

```
const data =
  [ { name: 'Trump'
    , children:
        [ { name: 'Trump Child 1', city: 'city1' }
        , { name: 'Trump Child 2', city: 'city2' }
        ]
    }
  , { name: 'Barack Obama'
    , children:
        [ { name: 'Barack Obama Child 1', city: 'city3' }
        , { name: 'Barack Obama Child 2', city: 'city4' }
        ]
    }
  , { name: 'Clinton'
    , children:
        [ { name: 'Clinton Child 1', city: 'city5' }
        , { name: 'Clinton Child 2', city: 'city6' }
        ]
    }
  , { name: 'Bush'
    , children:
        [ { name: 'Bush Child 1', city: 'city5' }
        , { name: 'Bush Child 2', city: 'city5' }
        ]
    }
  ]

console .log (findByCity ('city1', data))
// [ { name: 'Trump Child 1', city: 'city1' } ]

console .log (findByCity ('city5', data))
// [ { name: 'Clinton Child 1', city: 'city5' }
// , { name: 'Bush Child 1', city: 'city5' }
// , { name: 'Bush Child 2', city: 'city5' }
// ]
```

Another answer provided here would break if your data contained a `children`-less president. `findByCity` does not suffer from this problem

```
const data =
  [ // ...
  , { name: 'Bush'
    , children:
        [ { name: 'Bush Child 1', city: 'city5' }
        , { name: 'Bush Child 2', city: 'city5' }
        ]
    }

  // watch out for child-less presidents!
  , { name: 'Polk' }
  ]
```

Expand the program below to run it in your browser

```js
const findByCity = (city, data = {}) =>
  data .reduce
    ( (result, { children = [] }) =>
        result .concat (children .filter (c => c.city === city))
    , []
    )

const data =
  [ { name: 'Trump'
    , children:
        [ { name: 'Trump Child 1', city: 'city1' }
        , { name: 'Trump Child 2', city: 'city2' }
        ]
    }
  , { name: 'Barack Obama'
    , children:
        [ { name: 'Barack Obama Child 1', city: 'city3' }
        , { name: 'Barack Obama Child 2', city: 'city4' }
        ]
    }
  , { name: 'Clinton'
    , children:
        [ { name: 'Clinton Child 1', city: 'city5' }
        , { name: 'Clinton Child 2', city: 'city6' }
        ]
    }
  , { name: 'Bush'
    , children:
        [ { name: 'Bush Child 1', city: 'city5' }
        , { name: 'Bush Child 2', city: 'city5' }
        ]
    }
  , { name: 'Polk' }
  ]

console .log (findByCity ('city1', data))
// [ { name: 'Trump Child 1', city: 'city1' } ]
    
console .log (findByCity ('city5', data))
// [ { name: 'Clinton Child 1', city: 'city5' }
// , { name: 'Bush Child 1', city: 'city5' }
// , { name: 'Bush Child 2', city: 'city5' }
// ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had almost the same issue as here but for me i was looking for the overall Name of the element in this case the name of the father (for example name: 'Trump')
i just used a double find to make it as easy and efficient as possible ^^
My code :

```
let bigArray = [
  {
      Name: 'Trump',
      children: [
                   {Name: 'TrumpChild1', City: 'city1'}, 
                   {Name: 'TrumpChild2', City: 'city2'}
      ]
  },
  {
      Name: 'Barack Obama',
      children: [
                   {Name: 'Barack Obama Child1', City: 'city3'}, 
                   {Name: 'Barack Obama Child2', City: 'city4'}
      ]
  },
  {
      Name: 'Clinton',
      children: [
                   {Name: 'Clinton Child 1', City: 'city5'}, 
                   {Name: 'Clinton Child2', City: 'city6'}
      ]
  }
];

const element = bigArray.find((el) => el.children.find((item) => item.City === 'city2'))
const {Name: fatherName} = element
// for the element
console.log(element)
// for the father name 
console.log(fatherName)
```

if you just need the name you can remove element and change it with {Name: fatherName}