# Find Object inside an Array of nested Objects (Lodash / Javascript / Typescript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, lodash

Lets say have an Array of Objects that looks like this:

```
    let example = [
      {
        children: [{
          data: { id: 2, group: 1001, name: "Audi" },
        }],
        data: { id: 1, group: 1000, name: "Cars" }
      },
      {
        children: [{
          data: { id: 4, group: 1003, name: "Airbus A320" },
        }],
        data: { id: 3, group: 1002, name: "Planes" }
      },
      {
        children: [{
          data: { id: 6, group: 1005, name: "Departed" }
        }],
        data: { id: 5, group: 1006, name: "movies" }
      }
    ]
```

In my application the User selects a Tablerow and i get the selected Row Information aka the `'data' object` e.g.

```
{ id: 2, group: 1001, name: "Audi" }
```

Now i want to find that selected data object based on the `Id` in my Array using lodash or javascript/typescript.
How would i achive that? The children Array causes me problems.

EDIT: The Child of a Child should also be found.

```
{
        children: [{
          children: [{
             data: {id : 7, group 1001, name: "A8"},
             children: [{...}]
          }],
          data: { id: 2, group: 1001, name: "Audi" },
        }],
        data: { id: 1, group: 1000, name: "Cars" }
      }
```

Comment: Are you asking for an answer in TypeScript or JavaScript?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts In TypeScript or JavaScript doesnt matter at the moment.

Comment: Do you want to find the data object inside the array for the selected data object's `id` or do you want to find the data *inside* the `children` array for the select data object's `id` ?

Comment: I want to find both

Comment: Other possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381450/find-object-inside-array-inside-another-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/** find by id data using recursion */
function findById(data, id) {
  for (const datum of data) {
    if (datum.data.id == id) return datum
    if (datum.children) {
      let result = findById(datum.children, id)
      if (result) return result
    }
  }
}


let example = [{
    children: [{
      data: {
        id: 2,
        group: 1001,
        name: "Audi"
      },
    }],
    data: {
      id: 1,
      group: 1000,
      name: "Cars"
    }
  },
  {
    children: [{
      data: {
        id: 4,
        group: 1003,
        name: "Airbus A320"
      },
    }],
    data: {
      id: 3,
      group: 1002,
      name: "Planes"
    }
  },
  {
    children: [{
      data: {
        id: 6,
        group: 1005,
        name: "Departed"
      }
    }],
    data: {
      id: 5,
      group: 1006,
      name: "movies"
    }
  }
]



console.log(findById(example, 2))
```