# How to get a value of column 'b' from a 2d array where column 'a' matches a single array in javascript

Tags: javascript

New to javascript. Need some guidance on the problem below:

I have these arrays:

```
array1 = [['a1'], ['a2'], ['a3']];

array2 = [['a1',4], ['a3',3], ['a6',2]];
```

How can i get the matching arrays whereby array1 first col = array2 first col?
Example expected result:

```
[['a1',4], ['a3',3]]
```

I hope the question makes sense. Not really sure how to approach this since the structure of these two arrays are different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find Object inside Array inside another Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381450/find-object-inside-array-inside-another-array)

Comment: You just need to `flat()` the `array1` and then use `filter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` to filter out the elements. Inside filter method check if elements exist in array1. You can `flat` array1 to check effeciently.

```
let flatArr1 = array1.flat(); //["a1", "a2", "a3"]

const result = array2.filter(([x,y]) => flatArr1.includes(x));

console.log(result) // for instance
```

Comment: aa i didn't know we could use array [,] in filter. thanks so much!

Comment: You welcome. We pass a function to `filter` method. So inside that function you can do whatever you want, only condition `filter` expects return true or false, if true the element will be returned, else nothing will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for your problem:

```
    const compare = (array1, array2) => {
    let matched = [];
    const keys = [].concat(...array1);

    for(let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
            let result = array2[i][j];
            if(keys.includes(result)) {
                matched.push(array2[i])
            }
        }
    }

    console.log("matched: ", matched);
};
```